# Threading on Serial port

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, serial-port

Below is my code and it works to a degree. Unfortunately, it keeps locking up intermittently. I thought if I ran in separate thread it might help BUT I am just guessing. I am a bit lost. Any better solutions would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub SetTextScale(ByVal gText As String)
    Try
        If Me.txtOutPut.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetTextScale)
            Me.BeginInvoke(d, New Object() {gText})
                      txtOutPut.Text = gText  

            Else
                gText = Mid(gText, 7, 6)
            End If
            If IsNumeric(gText) Then
                txtGrossKg.Text = gText : gText = ""
                Call CalcNet()
            End If
        Else
            gText = Mid(gText, 7, 6)
                txtOutPut.Text = gText
           End If
    Catch
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it lock when you have to call CalcNet()?

Comment: Where does it lock?

Comment: Your number of `Else` and `End If` statements doesn't match the number of `If` statements you have. Please correct this as it makes the code very hard to interpret. I managed to see one thing though: You're accessing `txtOutput` right after calling `Me.BeginInvoke()`, which means you are still doing it in the background thread. You can not access _**any**_ UI element if you're in a background thread, that is, when `InvokeRequired = True`.

Comment: It locks when i try to do me.cmdClose button,

Comment: Calc et is just adding no's together, gross - tare = net, so no lock there

Comment: The serial code works ok, it doesn't lock until i try to close my form. I think i need to totally disable the serial port, maybe disable or something

Comment: My Close form code

Comment: Private Sub ClosePort()
        If ScaleSerial.IsOpen Then
            ScaleSerial.DiscardInBuffer()
            ScaleSerial.Close()
            ScaleSerial.Dispose()
        End If

Comment: There are some other check i do not  related so i deleted some of the code

Answer (score 0):

This is full code

```
    Try
        If Me.txtOutPut.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetTextScale)
            Me.BeginInvoke(d, New Object() {gText})
            If gLocal = 1111 Then
                If Mid(gText, 1, 2) = "et" Then gText = "" : Exit Sub
                ' ListBox1.Items.Add(gText)
                ' If ListBox1.Items.Count > 30 Then ListBox1.Items.Clear()
                txtOutPut.Text = gText : gStr1 = gText
                If InStr(gStr1, "+") Then
                    gInt1 = InStr(gStr1, "+")
                    gInt2 = InStr(gStr1, ".")
                    gStr2 = Mid(gStr1, gInt1 + 1, gInt2 - (gInt1 + 1)) & Mid(gStr1, gInt2, 3)
                    gText = gStr2
                End If
            Else
                gText = Mid(gText, 7, 6)
            End If
            If IsNumeric(gText) Then
                txtGrossKg.Text = gText : gText = ""
                Call CalcNet()
            Else
                gText = ""
            End If
        Else
            If gLocal <> 1111 Then
                'ListBox2.Items.Add(gText)
                'If ListBox2.Items.Count > 30 Then ListBox1.Items.Clear()

                gText = Mid(gText, 7, 6)
                txtOutPut.Text = gText
                If IsNumeric(gText) Then txtGrossKg.Text = gText : Call CalcNet()
            End If
            Call CalcNet()
            gText = ""
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
```